# Slick carousel in table

Tags: javascript, html, slick.js

Is there any way to use slick carousel in a table? I tried to use it in common way but then the slick element is the whole table and not the column.

Maybe someone knows what to do or knows a working plugin for that.

Here's a screenshot what i want to do:
[image]

HTML:

```
<table class="js-table-slider table-responsive">
<tr class="table-slider-row">
    <th class="table-slider-head">Top</th>
    <th class="table-slider-head">Zimmer</th>
    <th class="table-slider-head">Wohnfläche</th>
    <th class="table-slider-head">Geschoss</th>
    <th class="table-slider-head">Preis</th>
    <th class="table-slider-head">Grundriss</th>
</tr>
<tr class="table-slider-row">
    <td class="table-slider-cell">1</td>
    <td class="table-slider-cell">4</td>
    <td class="table-slider-cell">93,50 m2</td>
    <td class="table-slider-cell">EG</td>
    <td class="table-slider-cell">€ 195.000</td>
    <td class="table-slider-cell"><i class="far fa-image"></i></td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-slider-row">
    <td class="table-slider-cell">1</td>
    <td class="table-slider-cell">4</td>
    <td class="table-slider-cell">93,50 m2</td>
    <td class="table-slider-cell">EG</td>
    <td class="table-slider-cell">€ 195.000</td>
    <td class="table-slider-cell"><i class="far fa-image"></i></td>
</tr>
<tr class="table-slider-row">
    <td class="table-slider-cell">1</td>
    <td class="table-slider-cell">4</td>
    <td class="table-slider-cell">93,50 m2</td>
    <td class="table-slider-cell">EG</td>
    <td class="table-slider-cell">€ 195.000</td>
    <td class="table-slider-cell"><i class="far fa-image"></i></td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function (){
$('.js-table-slider').slick({
    dots: false,
    pauseOnHover: false,
    autoplay: false,
    dots: true,
    prevArrow: "<div class='table-slider-arrow left'><i class='fal fa-chevron-left'></i></div>",
    nextArrow: "<div class='table-slider-arrow right'><i class='fal fa-chevron-right'></i></div>"
});
});
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle or something where we can understand how did you implement slick for table ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/uq792sh3/7/

Comment: It will be hard to use slick for this purpose, you can find something else.. a suggestion is https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-To-Freeze-Table-Columns-Rows-On-Scroll.html

Comment: Did you get  a chance to find out how to do this? I want to implement right and left arrows for an Angular5 primeng grid with like 50 columns, so that user can click on the arrows to see the other columns in the grid. Horizontal scroll bar exists, but in case of too many rows, users have to scroll vertically to see the horizontal scroll which they don't like.